# Symfony 2 How to add a parameter to a controller response within a service

Tags: symfony, parameters, controller, listener

I'm currently developping an application with Syfmony 2 and i use fosuser to manage security. In the application a user can make many advertizing so the user object has one or many ardverts. When consulting the profil of an user i want to display all his adverts, using knp_paginator bundle, all this without having to override the default fosuser controller that is within a **listener**. But i don't know how to pass the knp_pagination array to the response of the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which method you are using in your Controller.

- If you use the `Template` annotation, then your action expect an array to be returned. Simply add `'adverts'` to this array.

  ```
  return array(
      // ...
      'adverts' => $adverts
  );
  ```
- If you use the `render` method of the Controller, the parameters array is supposed to be the second parameter of this method.

  ```
  return $this->render('your/template.html.twig', array(
      // ...
      'adverts' => $adverts
  ));
  ```
- If you return a `Response` instance, then you probably use `renderView` as well, which also needs the parameters array as its second parameter.

  ```
  return new Response($this->renderView('your/template.html.twig', array(
      // ...
      'adverts' => $adverts
  )));
  ```

Comment: Thank you I will try the last two, but i'm not sure if it will work because i'm in a Listener,

Comment: when i make return $this->render('myTemplate.html.twig',array('adverts'=> $adverts)) do the parameters set by fosuser controller are just added to my own or it just my own that will be passed to the template?

Comment: What do you mean by "parameters set by fosuser controller"? Can you show us some code?

Comment: i suppose that by default when fosuser render the route /profile, the method renderView take an array of some parameters (at least the user)

Comment: To be brief i want to add my own parameters to that one but in a listener

Comment: I don't think that's possible. In my opinion, you should create a custom `profile` action, or at least override FOSUser's `profile` (http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html)

Comment: I finally overrided FOSUser's profile controller. thank you